# How to use scopes to join across multiple tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to ROR and I am trying to understand scopes. In my current implementation I am getting all the Processors and displaying it in the view.

```
class ProcessorsController
  def index
    @processors = Processor.all    
  end
end
```

**I want to modify this so I can get only the processors where the user is admin**. This is how my relations are set up.

```
class Processor
  belongs_to :feed

  #SCOPES (what I have done so far)
  scope :feed, joins(:feed)
  scope :groups, joins(:feed => :groups).join(:user).where(:admin => true)
end

class Feed < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :groups
  scope :admin,     where(:admin     => true)
end
```

I was able to do this in my pry

```
pry(main)> Processor.find(63).feed.groups.first.user.admin?
```

PS: could someone provide some good resources where I could learn how to use scopes if the relationships are complex.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
scope :with_admin, -> { joins(:feed => { :groups => :user }).where('users.admin' => true) }
```

As for the resources, have you gone through the [official documentation on ActiveRecord joins](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables)?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes I did go thorough that doc, but I didn't catch the use of multiple joins.

Comment: Your answer really illustrated me on how to use joins inside scopes. It's just the same. One just need to 'omit' the Model name part before calling the method.

Answer (score 0):

you do not need scopes... you can get only the processors where the user is admin using relations and conditions:

```
class Feed < ActiveRecord::Base
   ...
   has_one :user, through: :groups
end


class Processor
  ...
  has_one :admin, through: :feed, source: :user, conditions: ['users.admin = 1']
end
```

Comment: I dont understand, are you suggesting me to modify my relation ? What if I want to keep my existing relation ?

Comment: you can safely append two relations i proposed without modifying yours